# Need to pass prop(header_title) to layout.vue from news.vue

Tags: meteor, vue.js, vuejs2

The project is built on Vue.js on top of Meteor.js. I need to pass a dynamic value from news.vue to layout.vue header_title area (refer layout.vue png).

I have set layout.vue file as the main layout of the app with navigation menu of the app and routing is also handling from layout.vue.

Related screenshots:

index.js

[image]

layout.vue

[image]

Comment: Don't post screenshots, post code.

Answer (score 1):

Use `props` in your `Layout.vue`

---

Layout.vue

```
export default {
  props: ['headerTitle'],
  // your other stuff here
}
```

---

News.vue

```
<layout :headerTitle="header_title"></layout>
```